# A dice game is played where you are given 10 initial rolls. If you roll a 6 you get another roll. What is the average number of rolls?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I know without the initial rolls. If you continue on 6 and stop on 1-5, the problem will follow a geometric distribution where the average number of rolls will be 1/p, where p is the probability of success (we will consider rolling 1-5 a success) or in this case 6/5 = 1.2 average rolls per game played.

However the initial rolls have thrown me for a loop.

For clarification, it's a single die, the first 10 rolls are guaranteed, each 6 you get adds one to your total rolls left. You stop playing the game once you are on your last roll and get a 1-5.

Comment: It's just like playing 10 separate games.

Comment: To emphasize, it makes no difference whether this was all played using a single die, or if you used ten differently colored dice... after having "ended" with one die you move to the next colored die and starting again.

Comment: Here's a simple [sim in Sage / Python](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj72OgzAQhHueYkpQiM40KSI5SnXlvQJawjoxARsZR_f68Q_hxG1haz_NzGqUsxMcmT58epqt81iY-zoxbXxRXMPLjm6-6FlhIm3KO028yEYIUaMj85RN1rfRKn-s4Rr08rZ9zT15lt80LlydC4SJknITV4l562mEhEibsg4ttImRd87HVnOcLgjj0Q0MmzPO70OPHEQXiD9P9h0lmh0acPiPtPo0L0OpUwUpcdoH5bCdMxcIaEhodtGfYA01WloXfCG3qd7OimJd&lang=sage) you can play with online. A standard game has 1 roll in the bank, the OP problem has 10 rolls in the bank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method $A$:

Instead of one die being thrown 10 times, suppose you have 10 dice thrown once. Only those that fall on $6$ are rerolled.
The expected number of throws of each die is as you said $1.2$ and the total (linearity of expectation) is $12$.

Method $B$:

Let $X\sim Bin(10,\tfrac{1}{6})$ the number of $6$ in the first 10 rolls. Given $X$, the number of additional rolls is distributed according to negative binom distribution with the parameters $X$ and $\tfrac{5}{6}$.
The expected number of rolls given $X$ is $\tfrac{X}{5/6}+10$ and the expected number of rolls all together ($E(X)=10\cdot \tfrac{1}{6}$) is 12.

Comment: I don't think this is true, though I wonder if linearity of the expected value can be used in the correct way to have an easier answer. It is false because if you consider the case where we have only one initial roll, you give the answer 1.2, whereas you are already guaranteed to have at least 2 rolls.

Comment: Why 2? If I understood it correctly, if you have one initial roll you have 1 for sure, and only if it landed on 6 you have another one.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but if you have no initial rolls, then you already roll once and if it's 6, then you roll again. If you have one initial roll, you roll once, if it's not 6, you start over, i.e., you roll again and play the game as if you have no initial rolls.

Comment: $10$ rolls are guaranteed.

Comment: @trueblueanil $10$ or $11$? If you have no initial rolls, i.e., $0$ initial roll, then $1$ roll is guaranteed as the OP explained. If you have $10$ initial rolls, then if all of them lands between $1-5$, then you just play the same game with $0$ extra rolls.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the meaning of $0$ initial rolls. If you have $0$ initial rolls, you don't roll. If you have one initial roll, this is a geometric random variable. If you have $2$ initial rolls, you roll twice. Then based on the results you either roll again twice (after $6,6$) or once (one $6$) or none.

Comment: @Levent:This is exactly what OP writes: "For clarification, it's a single die, the first 10 rolls are guaranteed, each 6 you get adds one to your total rolls left."

Comment: @YJT I mean, isn't this what the first sentence says? Without the initial rolls, you just roll once and play the game. I considered the 10 rolls as extra. Maybe I misunderstood. I leave the floor to OP for clarification.

Comment: @Levent Most probably OP meant that he knows the solution of the problem with **one** initial roll.

Comment: @Levent while any confusion by an answerer and request for clarification warrants clarification by the OP, the game style described in the post and language used is common enough.  If going by your interpretation of the alluded to "10 rolls" were in fact extra on top of a first roll, we can still approach with linearity of expectation.  The answer there with $n$ "*extra*" rolls on top of a first roll would be $(n+1)\cdot 1.2$.  Your first comment then, it would be under that interpretation $2\cdot 1.2=2.4$.  That said, I agree with the interpretations used here by YJT and trueblue et al.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is I know the solution if the game started with 1 initial roll, as we would need that initial roll the even play the game in the first place. This solution absolutely makes sense I cant believe I didn't see it before. Thank you so much! For some reason my brain refused to see them as independent events.

Answer (score 0):

Say $e(n)$ is the average number of rolls when you are given $n$ initial rolls. If you roll, say $k$ sixes in the initial rolls, then after the initial rolls, you have $k$ initial rolls and it's like you play the same game with $k$ initial rolls. Hence, if you roll $k$ sixes, then the average number of rolls equals $e(k)+n$. So we have the formula
$$
e(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^{n-i}\big(\frac{1}{6}\big)^i (e(i)+n).
$$

You already know that $e(0)=1.2.$

Edit: This answer is true if the game is like this: You roll a dice 10 times, and count the number of sixes, say $k$. Then you start the game by rolling a die, each time you roll $6$, you win one roll, each time you roll $1-5$, you lose a roll.

Comment: Edited my answer to include method B. I think that an adaptation of this can simplify your calculation (based on the rules you describe in the edit).

Comment: While this answer is mathematically sound, surely the point of the exercise as it was assigned to the OP is to emphasize the usefulness of linearity of expectation which completely trivializes the problem, allowing you to calculate the answer in your head.  This approach is far too clunky to be useful in practice, even if it does potentially highlight interesting identities.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's not a problem that I'm very familiar with, I approached the problem too straight. Even if I understood correctly, it is clear that the formula actually gives $(n+1)\cdot 1/2$.